# Create temporary table in MySQL from Java

Tags: java, mysql, temp-tables

I have this:

```
public static void createTemporaryTable() {
        Statement s = null;
        sentence = "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE Book (ISBN int NOT NULL, " +
                "title varchar(45), author varchar(45), price double, PRIMARY KEY  (`ISBN`));";

        try {
            s = Conexion.getInstancia().createStatement();
            s.executeUpdate(sentence);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                s.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Then:

```
public class System {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SqlSentencesList.createTemporaryTable();
    }

}
```

But when I execute `select * from Book`, MySQL tells me `Book` table doesn't exists. I ain't getting any error messages from java, so the table should be created, but it's not.

If I execute the same sql sentence for creating the temporary table directly in mysql, it works fine.

This's my `Conexion` class:

```
public class Conexion {

    private static Connection conexion = null;



    private Conexion() {

    }

    public static Connection getInstancia() {
        if (conexion == null) {
            try {
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                conexion = DriverManager.getConnection(
                        "jdbc:mysql://localhost/Esquema_VentaLibros","gustavo", "123581321");

            } catch (SQLException sqlex) {
                sqlex.printStackTrace();
            } catch(ClassNotFoundException cnfex) {
                cnfex.printStackTrace();
            }
            return conexion;
        }
        else {
            return conexion;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you use the same user when trying the query directly in MySQL and in your application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Temporary tables are automatically dropped when a connection is closed.

See the [MySQL CREATE TABLE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table.html) documentation for details:

> You can use the TEMPORARY keyword when creating a table. A TEMPORARY table is visible only to the current connection, and is dropped automatically when the connection is closed. This means that two different connections can use the same temporary table name without conflicting with each other or with an existing non-TEMPORARY table of the same name. (The existing table is hidden until the temporary table is dropped.)

If you want to create a temporary table to do some work in, you should create it when you begin your work, and execute your UPDATE/SELECT statements against it. It will automatically drop when you close your connection, and it won't conflict with other connections using the same temporary table name.

Comment: But I'm not closing the connection.

Comment: Where are you executing your `SELECT * FROM Book`? I don't see it in your main method. If you're getting the same connection back from `getInstancia()` then it should still be visible. But if you access the DB from the mysql commandline or another program, it won't.

Answer (score 1):

Temporary tables are per database connection. So if you're trying to access a temporary table from another connection, you won't see it.

Comment: So, if I execute `select * from Book` from Java it should work fine, right?

Comment: Depends on how you handle database connections. Do you open a new one before each query? Do you have a pool of connections and `Conexion.getInstancia()` gets a random one of them? Each of these scenarios could lead to using different connections when creating the temporary table and when trying to access it.

Comment: I just close the statement, but not the connection. I'll put my `Conexion` class.

Comment: Do a quick test first - execute another statement in the `createTemporaryTable()` method. Try to `select * from Books` right after you create the temporary table.